# Cloudwatch rule with different input

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

How to create a AWS cloudwatch rule with different input everytime when it is scheduled?
Example: I want to schedule a lambda in every 1 hour, first time it should take "xyz" as an input using cloudwatch rule,
2nd time the input should be "123",
3rd time the input should be "78ds" and so on.

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in way to do this. Scheduled event data does not include any information about number of invocations. Input transformer is used to format event data and cannot be used in this case.
You can however pass your data in as a constant (JSON text) and create a logic to pick the right value.

Two suggestions:

1. Store a value representing Lambda invocation count in a DynamoDb table. When your function is invoked, it fetches this value from the table, increments it and writes it back. Index gives you which value to pick from the input data. If you have N input values, use index = value mod N.
2. Determine the index based on time of the invocation using simple math.

Answer (score 0):

- worth checking if you can use `input Transformer` of `Create rule` `Target` to manipulate the input to the trarget to be invoked [aws tutorial input transformer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/CloudWatch-Events-Input-Transformer-Tutorial.html)